# Looking for a jQuery for replace a p tag with two p tags

Tags: jquery

What jQuery do I have to write if I want to change the **Current** with the **Required** one.

**Current**

jQuery Format Big

(this is one line content)

**Required**
(below one is a two line content with different font size)

jQuery Format Big

jQuery Format Small

Comment: Current : you posted quesion is unclear. Required : Please post the question clearly. Thanks

Comment: Spend some time and formulate the question properly before posting any it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/) method in jquery to setthe content of a div.

Find the working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/t11yuvq3/2/

Find the code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#btn_click').on('click', function () {
            $("#container").html("<p id='required1' style='font-size: 125%;'>jQuery Format Big</p><p id='required2' style='font-size: 75%;'>jQuery Format Small</p>");
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <p id="current">jQuery Format Normal</p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="btn_click">Replace p</button>
    </body>
</html>
```